# How to convert timestamp with ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to convert time with ruby? My program prints the time stamp like this: `10/18/2107 14:08:09`, but I want it to be like this: `2017 M10 18, Wed 14:08:09 GMT+02:00`. From what I understand, the time stamp I want comes in Joda-Time.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you know it’s `GMT+02:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the string you can parse it to DateTime passing the format, and then format the output string:

```
date_time = '10/18/2107 14:08:09'

puts DateTime.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
             .strftime('%Y M%m %d, %a %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Note it's Tuesday and the time zone it's specified as 00:00.

Comment: So i want to scipt it so it change the timestamp for alot of file, so the time wont be the same on every file.

Comment: The  problem with you code, is that i need to know the time stamp before and put it into the script.

I got a file event log with over 1mil timestamps, none of them are the same time. So my question is, is there a way to make a string of some sort,that take and convert every timestamp to Joda-time

Comment: "Is there a way to make a string of some sort" -  yes, I think there are more than 1 way, maybe you'd have to convert each timestamp in your file. I can't see how looks your file, so I can't tell you in depth how. Do you have access to what's creating the log? maybe you could start there.

Comment: its from a Event log. So it print it out like this: 10/18/2107 14:08:09..  But lets say 1 event log have over 1-2mil timestamps. I want the scipt to automatic change it to joda time. i get a few events a day, so i want it to be automatic.

Comment: Yes, I understand, you can or update all the dates in your log or modify the way they're being written. Does this answer respond to your question (see title)?. If so, then close and you can create a new question with your next step and doubts.

Comment: So i tried to make a script says: require 'date'
items = $current_selected_items
items.each do |email|
properties = email.getProperties
date_time = properties["CreationDate"]
puts DateTime.strptime(date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
             .strftime('%Y M%m %d, %a %H:%M:%S %Z')
puts date
end  But it seems ruby cant find a date from my varible "creationdate". So in my program the date is behind properties["CreationDate"]

Comment: You need to open the file, read it and modify it. You can create a separate and detailed question this way any user on SO can take a time and help you. You can close this question by accepting it, I'll be looking for updates.

Comment: @Deathleecher this perfectly answers your question, that was about date/time conversion, not about files, event logs etc. You are to accept it, nobody here will write the whole code for you for free.